# cumulative probability distribution

Tags: probability

> Let the joint density of the random vector $(X; Y )$ be $f(x; y) = c$, if $1 < x < 3$ and $2 < y < 5$, and $0$ otherwise (for a suitable $c$). How can we calculate the probability $P(X < 2; Y > 4)$?

I tried so far the following:

$$P(X < 2; Y > 4)=\int_1^2\int_4^5 c \,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx=c.$$

Thanks.

Comment: How? Using the definition of the PDF, most assuredly... What is $P((X,Y)\in B)$ already, in terms of the PDF of $(X,Y)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are halfway done -- you have found that the answer is $c$.  All that is left to do is to figure out what the "suitable" value of $c$ is.

To do this, you need to use the fact that the total probability is 1.

That is, you need to solve this for $c$:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
f(x;y) = 1
$$
$$
\int_{1}^{3}
\int_{2}^{5}
c = 1
$$
$$6c=1$$
$$c=\frac 16$$